# How to disable mouse wheel scrolling over a type "number" input in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input, numeric

I'm using MUI type="number" textfields, but when I focus it and then scroll the mousewheel, the value of the input changes. I've readed about adding Blur after scroll, but I don't wanna blur the field. I've readed too about adding Blur and Focus again, but the behaviour isn't good enough.

Could somebody help me? Thanks a lot! :)

I'm using React 18 & MUI v5.

To reproduce this behaviour, you can go to https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/, click in a type number textfield, and then scroll OVER the field. You will see how the value changes.

I've tried using blur and focus, but this behaviour is not good enough

Comment: I can't reproduce that behaviour here https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with SurveyJS, here are 2 ways to solve it below!

```
const scrollableElements = 
 document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]');
    scrollableElements.forEach((item: HTMLElement) => {
      item.addEventListener("wheel", (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });
 });

const scrollableElements = 
 document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]');
 scrollableElements.forEach((item: HTMLElement) => {
  item.setAttribute("onwheel", "return false");
 });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use a `type={'text'}` TextField and then add inputProps that exclude non-numeric inputs

```
<TextField inputProps={{ inputMode: 'numeric', pattern: '[0-9]*' }} />
```

As shown in the MUI docs: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/

Answer (score 0):

You can **disable** the **mouse wheel scrolling** over a **type "number" input** in React by using the following piece of code. It will also prevent the default behavior for the **up and down arrow keys**.

```
const handleKeyDown = (e: any) => {
    if (e.key === "ArrowUp" || e.key === "ArrowDown") {
      e.preventDefault();
   }
};

<input
  type="number"
  onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
  onWheel={(e) => e.target.blur()}
  // other props...
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `onKeyUp` instead of `onChange`
onKeyUp not fire with you scroll the mouse

```
 onKeyUp={(e) => {
     console.log(e.key)
     console.log(e.target.value)
 }}
```